# how to send emails at periodic intervals using PHP

Tags: php, email

My site is running on LINUX server and I want to send an email to users who have not logged onto my site for more than a week. I'm trying to find a readymade script to do so to save my time and coding. Can someone please point me to a site or a service which allows me to add such functionality to my site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's called a cron -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cron on Linux is great.

First: create a script to check who you want to send email to.

Second: create a cron and run it once or twice a day.